# how to send request with clientID and secret with flutter

Tags: spring, flutter, oauth-2.0

Hello im new to flutter and i've built a spring boot app based on oauth2 that expose an api that returns a access-token, and i want to use the login api with flutter, but i don't know how i can add the basic auth which means adding the clientId and secret to my request any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oAuth2` and `Basic auth` are two different methods of authentication.

If you really meant basic auth, simplest way could be to add the `BASE64` encoded string of `username:password` in the Authorization header with a `Basic`  string at the begining.

For eg: for the credential usr:pwd, `Authorization` header value becomes `Basic dXNyOnB3ZA==`

You can encode using https://www.base64encode.org/

For oAuth2, you might need additional libraries. refer : https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2

Comment: Thank you very much the first option with Base64 worked for me.